# OBS in Linux can't find NDI sources from other PC running Skype in Windows

Tags: linux, obs

As SkypeforLinux has no NDI support, I decided to split the work between two computers. A windows laptop to manage Skype videochatting with NDI support and a Archlinux PC with OBS and the obs-ndi plugin.

Both computers are wired to the same LAN. I have tried it with a third Windows Laptop with OBS installed, and it finds de ndi sources (form the other laptop Skype) without problems.

But when I try it with the Archlinux PC (no errors of any kind in the log,  ndi initialized succesfully), no ndi sources are available in Source Name.
[image: OBS screenshot]

Any clue?